# MySQL issue "Received packet in the wrong sequence" . Next.js 14.0.4 project

Tags: mysql, next.js

In my `Next.js` project, when I run in development mode, it works fine. However, when I attempt (build then start), the following error occurs:

```
Error: Received packet in the wrong sequence.{
  e: Error: Received packet in the wrong sequence.
      at a._parsePacket (/Users/callpro/lime-dashboard-v2/.next/server/chunks/4679.js:50:90760)
      at E._parsePacket (/Users/callpro/lime-dashboard-v2/.next/server/chunks/4679.js:50:85839)
      at E.write (/Users/callpro/lime-dashboard-v2/.next/server/chunks/4679.js:50:80036)
      at a.write (/Users/callpro/lime-dashboard-v2/.next/server/chunks/4679.js:50:87298)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/callpro/lime-dashboard-v2/.next/server/chunks/4679.js:50:55253)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/callpro/lime-dashboard-v2/.next/server/chunks/4679.js:50:54362)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
      at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
      --------------------
      at a._enqueue (/Users/callpro/lime-dashboard-v2/.next/server/chunks/4679.js:50:88666)
      at a.handshake (/Users/callpro/lime-dashboard-v2/.next/server/chunks/4679.js:50:87421)
      at A.connect (/Users/callpro/lime-dashboard-v2/.next/server/chunks/4679.js:50:56118)
      at /Users/callpro/lime-dashboard-v2/.next/server/chunks/4679.js:37:7179
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at u.acquireRawConnection (/Users/callpro/lime-dashboard-v2/.next/server/chunks/4679.js:37:7057)
      at create (/Users/callpro/lime-dashboard-v2/.next/server/chunks/4679.js:5:874)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    code: 'PROTOCOL_INCORRECT_PACKET_SEQUENCE',
    fatal: true
  }
}
```

How can I implement the configuration `optimization:{minimize:false}` in my `next.config`?

Comment: I think this means the mysql client library is incompatible with the server.

Answer (score 0):

Solved :)

```js
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    // Remove TerserPlugin if not needed for minification
    if (!config.optimization) {
      config.optimization = {};
    }
    if (!config.optimization.minimizer) {
      config.optimization.minimizer = [];
    }
    
    // Add TerserPlugin with optimized options
    config.optimization.minimizer.push(new TerserPlugin({
      terserOptions: {
        mangle: false,
      },
      // Limit parallelism to reduce memory usage
      parallel: false,
    }));

    config.optimization.minimize = false;

    return config;
  },
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).